# Unable to create image from compressed texture data (S3TC)

Tags: c++, image, image-compression, vulkan

I've been trying to load compressed images with S3TC (BC/DXT) compression in Vulkan, but so far I haven't had much luck.

Here is what the Vulkan specification says about compressed images:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/dataformat/specs/1.1/dataformat.1.1.html#S3TC:

> Compressed texture images stored using the S3TC compressed image formats are represented as a collection of 4×4 texel blocks, where each block contains 64 or 128 bits of texel data. The image is encoded as a normal 2D raster image in which each 4×4 block is treated as a single pixel.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/xhtml/vkspec.html#resources-images:

> For images created with linear tiling, rowPitch, arrayPitch and depthPitch describe the layout of the subresource in linear memory. For uncompressed formats, rowPitch is the number of bytes between texels with the same x coordinate in adjacent rows (y coordinates differ by one). arrayPitch is the number of bytes between texels with the same x and y coordinate in adjacent array layers of the image (array layer values differ by one). depthPitch is the number of bytes between texels with the same x and y coordinate in adjacent slices of a 3D image (z coordinates differ by one). Expressed as an addressing formula, the starting byte of a texel in the subresource has address:
>
> > // (x,y,z,layer) are in texel coordinates
> >
> > address(x,y,z,layer) = layer*arrayPitch + z*depthPitch + y*rowPitch + x*texelSize + offset
>
> For compressed formats, the rowPitch is the number of bytes between compressed blocks in adjacent rows. arrayPitch is the number of bytes between blocks in adjacent array layers. depthPitch is the number of bytes between blocks in adjacent slices of a 3D image.
>
> > // (x,y,z,layer) are in block coordinates
> >
> > address(x,y,z,layer) = layer*arrayPitch + z*depthPitch + y*rowPitch + x*blockSize + offset;
>
> arrayPitch is undefined for images that were not created as arrays. depthPitch is defined only for 3D images.
>
> For color formats, the aspectMask member of VkImageSubresource must be VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT. For depth/stencil formats, aspect must be either VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT or VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_STENCIL_BIT. On implementations that store depth and stencil aspects separately, querying each of these subresource layouts will return a different offset and size representing the region of memory used for that aspect. On implementations that store depth and stencil aspects interleaved, the same offset and size are returned and represent the interleaved memory allocation.

My image is a normal 2D image (0 layers, 1 mipmap), so there's no *arrayPitch* or *depthPitch*. Since S3TC compression is directly supported by the hardware, it should be possible to use the image data without decompressing it first. In OpenGL this can be done using *glCompressedTexImage2D*, and this has worked for me in the past.

In OpenGL I've used GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT as image format, for Vulkan I'm using VK_FORMAT_BC1_RGBA_UNORM_BLOCK, which should be equivalent.
Here's my code for mapping the image data:

```
auto dds = load_dds("img.dds");
auto *srcData = static_cast<uint8_t*>(dds.data());
auto *destData = static_cast<uint8_t*>(vkImageMapPtr); // Pointer to mapped memory of VkImage
destData += layout.offset(); // layout = VkImageLayout of the image
assert((w %4) == 0);
assert((h %4) == 0);
assert(blockSize == 8); // S3TC BC1
auto wBlocks = w /4;
auto hBlocks = h /4;
for(auto y=decltype(hBlocks){0};y<hBlocks;++y)
{
    auto *rowDest = destData +y *layout.rowPitch(); // rowPitch is 0
    auto *rowSrc = srcData +y *(wBlocks *blockSize);
    for(auto x=decltype(wBlocks){0};x<wBlocks;++x)
    {
        auto *pxDest = rowDest +x *blockSize;
        auto *pxSrc = rowSrc +x *blockSize; // 4x4 image block
        memcpy(pxDest,pxSrc,blockSize); // 64Bit per block
    }
}
```

And here's the code for initializing the image:

```
vk::Device device = ...; // Initialization
vk::AllocationCallbacks allocatorCallbacks = ...; // Initialization
[...] // Load the dds data
uint32_t width = dds.width();
uint32_t height = dds.height();
auto format = dds.format(); // = vk::Format::eBc1RgbaUnormBlock;

vk::Extent3D extent(width,height,1);

vk::ImageCreateInfo imageInfo(
    vk::ImageCreateFlagBits(0),
    vk::ImageType::e2D,format,
    extent,1,1,
    vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1,
    vk::ImageTiling::eLinear,
    vk::ImageUsageFlagBits::eSampled | vk::ImageUsageFlagBits::eColorAttachment,
    vk::SharingMode::eExclusive,
    0,nullptr,
    vk::ImageLayout::eUndefined
);

vk::Image img = nullptr;
device.createImage(&imageInfo,&allocatorCallbacks,&img);

vk::MemoryRequirements memRequirements;
device.getImageMemoryRequirements(img,&memRequirements);
uint32_t typeIndex = 0;
get_memory_type(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits(),vk::MemoryPropertyFlagBits::eHostVisible,typeIndex); // -> typeIndex is set to 1
auto szMem = memRequirements.size();
vk::MemoryAllocateInfo memAlloc(szMem,typeIndex);
vk::DeviceMemory mem;
device.allocateMemory(&memAlloc,&allocatorCallbacks,&mem); // Note: Using the default allocation (nullptr) doesn't change anything
device.bindImageMemory(img,mem,0);

uint32_t mipLevel = 0;
vk::ImageSubresource resource(
    vk::ImageAspectFlagBits::eColor,
    mipLevel,
    0
);
vk::SubresourceLayout layout;
device.getImageSubresourceLayout(img,&resource,&layout);

auto *srcData = device.mapMemory(mem,0,szMem,vk::MemoryMapFlagBits(0));
[...] // Map the dds-data (See code from first post)
device.unmapMemory(mem);
```

The code runs without issues, however the resulting image isn't correct. This is the source image:

[image: Black/Pink checkerboard pattern]

And this is the result:

[image: Green/Black checkerboard pattern, much smaller than source image]

I'm certain that the problem lies in the first code snipped I've posted, however, in case it doesn't, I've written a small adaption of the triangle demo from the Vulkan SDK which produces the same result. It can be downloaded [here](http://sciolyte.com/sharex/tri_dds.zip). The source-code is included, all I've changed from the triangle demo are the "demo_prepare_texture_image"-function in *tri.c* (Lines 803 to 903) and the "dds.cpp" and "dds.h" files. "dds.cpp" contains the code for loading the dds, and mapping the image memory.

I'm using [gli](http://gli.g-truc.net/0.8.1/index.html) to load the dds-data (Which is supposed to "work perfectly with Vulkan"), which is also included in the download above. To build the project, the Vulkan SDK include directory has to be added to the "tri" project, and the path to the dds has to be changed (tri.c, Line 809).

The source image ("x64/Debug/test.dds" in the project) uses DXT1 compression. I've tested in on different hardware as well, with the same result.

Any example code for initializing/mapping compressed images would also help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is actually quite simple - in the `demo_prepare_textures` function, the first line, there is a variable `tex_format`, which is set to `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` (which is what it is in the original sample). This eventually gets used to create the VkImageView. If you just change this to `VK_FORMAT_BC1_RGBA_UNORM_BLOCK`, it displays the texture correctly on the triangle.

As an aside - you can verify that your texture loaded correctly, with `RenderDoc`, which comes with the Vulkan SDK installation. Doing a capture of it, the and looking in the `TextureViewer` tab, the `Inputs` tab shows that your texture looks identical to the one on disk, even with the incorrect format.

[image: fixed image]

Comment: If I change the format, the resulting image is even more messed up (http://sciolyte.com/sharex/2016-03-25_15-35-40.gif). RenderDoc crashes immediately after trying to run any program through it. Did the demo actually work for you with that change? Did you change anything else?

Comment: If it's working for you, could you please provide your code with the changes? I still haven't gotten it to work on my side.

Comment: Other than the loading path of the DDS, and some project settings to use my installed Vulkan 1.0.5 SDK, and the VS 120 toolchain, I did not change anything else from the tri_dds.zip download. Perhaps a driver issue? Maybe attach your vulkaninfo?

Comment: As it turns out, it seems to be indeed a driver issue. I've tested in on two different AMD systems (Image was corrupt on both) and two Nvidia systems (Image showed up perfectly fine on both). I've reported it to AMD, still waiting for a response.

Comment: Apparently AMD drivers are much more sensitive to resource transitions being done correctly (whereas Nvidia are very forgiving), which might explain it. I haven't tested them myself.